# What happens when we connect one end of a wire to the main supply and the other end to ground?

Tags: electricity, electric-current

If we connect a wire to the main supply(240v) and if we ground it, what will happen ?? Will there be a current flow ? Will I get a huge electricity bill at the end of the month ??
Also if we connect a bulb in middle of the wire, will it light ?
Thanks

Comment: If you are lucky it will trigger a ground fault.  As for the light bulb, if not rated for the actual current it's likely to explode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the electric network common e.g. in Europe, the current will flow through the wire into earth. The current will depend on the soil humidity and wire termination; it may or may not be sufficient to light a bulb.

With very good (and bulky) termination, the current may be so high that the circuit breaker trips (typically 10 or 16 A).

More probably, if installed, the *residual current* breaker may detect a potentially dangerous situation where the current does not return by the second conductor, and trip much sooner when the current to earth is over several tens of mA.

While it is a feasible experiment, I do not recommend to do this at home.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect your wire to ground you will create a circuit via earth.

The current that flows depends mainly on the impedance of the earth and earthing arrangement (also on the impedance of the wiring and any other conductive return paths). If the main earth of the suppy point is a at a local transformer the current can be considered to flow from that supply point and return there via earth.

If the impedance is low a high current will flow and you'll blow a fuse/bulb or trip a breaker/RCD.

If the impedance is within a certain range a the bulbs rated current will flow and it will light.

If the impedance is high the current will be low and nothing much will happen.

The earthing impedance depends on soil type, moisture, distance to earth electrodes etc..

I do not recommend trying it at home.